# node redis remote connection throwing exception

Tags: redis, node-redis, econnreset

i use to connect to my local redis instance like so(when my client and redis server were on the same box,

```
var client=redis.createClient();
```

and i can easily connect to the server.

however, if my redis server is on a remote machine host_name:6379, I cant make createClient function to work.

var client=redis.createClient('6379', 'host_name', {no_ready_check:true}); //gives the below error

```
Error: Redis connection to host_name:6379 failed - read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:559:26)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

what am i doing wrong. the remote server is a linux machine that i need to ssh into using my username password. How would i provide that info inside createclient function.

any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Have you tried the host ip instead of host name?

Comment: Is the remote server's 6379 port open for external connection?

Comment: @ShriramManoharan yes. i've bound the ip to 0.0.0.0 and also I have redisdesktopmanager GUI connected to the redis server. the way i had to establish a connection to the redis server from redisdesktopmanager was to provide the host and port AND also provide SSH tunneling information (my linux username/password) and SSH port (22)

Comment: so essentially, its my node app thats giving me the error. as I am able to access the redis server from redisdesktopmanager in remote just fine

Comment: @KarthikeyanGopall yes . I tried IP address as well